# Glm::rotate() showing error NO MATCHING FUNCTION FOUND

Tags: android-studio, graphics, opengl-es, android-ndk, rotational-matrices

Using Android NDK , while using glm::rotate function it shows no matching function is there and the object remains constant without rotating.
Help me guys...

see the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post photos of code - cut and paste the code into a code block.

Comment: Have you included the header? #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

Comment: Please copy paste your code and format it properly